# Is it possible to setState in the constructor?

Tags: react-native

I was trying to setState in the constructor but somehow it doesn't work.

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  example: false
 }

 this.setState({example: true}) //Not doing anything

}
```

Neither does this work:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  example: false
 }

 this.state.example = true //Not doing anything

}
```

My reason being:

```
constructor(props) {
 super(props);
 this.state = {
  panResponders: []
 }

 let panResponders = []
 for(let i=0; i < 5; i++){
  panResponders.push(this.panResponder(i), this.state.showDraggable)
 }
 this.setState({panResponders: panResponders}) //I want to do this
}
```

I want to be able to add an array to the state later in the constructor for various reasons

**EDIT:**

I tried in componentDidMount the first `console.log()` is an array but `setState()` doesn't work on it it's still null.

```
  componentDidMount(){
    const {question, actions} = this.props
    this.panResponder = (number, draggables) => PanResponder.create({
        onStartShouldSetPanResponder    : () => true,
        onPanResponderMove              : Animated.event([null,{
            dx  : this.state.pan[number].x,
            dy  : this.state.pan[number].y
        }]),
        onPanResponderRelease           : (e, gesture) => {
            if(this.isDropZone(gesture)){
                this.setState({
                    showDraggable : draggables
                });
            }else{
                Animated.spring(
                    this.state.pan[number],
                    {toValue:{x:0,y:0}}
                ).start();
            }
        }
    });

    let panResponders = []
    for(let i=0; i < question.currentQuestion.antwoorden.length; i++){
      panResponders.push(this.panResponder(i), this.state.showDraggable)
    }
    console.log(panResponders) //Populated array
    console.log(this.state.panResponders) // null
    this.setState({panResponders: "panResponders"})
    console.log(this.state.panResponders) // null
  }
```

Comment: Could you please explain why do you need it?

Comment: I have editted my question

Comment: Can't you handle the panresponders in the componentDidMount function instead?

Comment: Yes I could try that thanks

Comment: I tried it and it doesn't work. Somehow setState still doesn't populate it.

Comment: I also editted my question and added the code

Comment: I was wrong it only didn't update within componentDidMount() which is normal so that solution worked thanks! If you post it as an answer I will accept it.

Comment: Is it not possible to calculate the array `panResponders` in the constructor and then a bit later use `this.state = { panResponders: panResponders }` ?

Comment: I had tried that but unfortunately that wasn't possible in my case because of the other things I use with it. It works the way I want it using `componentWillMount()` with hopefully no down sides to it.

Comment: Any updates here? I'm having the same problem? I've tried in componentDidMount() and componentWillMount().